# Grabber for splitting in UWP

Tags: c++, windows, microsoft-metro, win-universal-app, samplegrabber

I need your advice. I'd like to develop the app for audio/video splitting  using Metro interface.

Usually I use DirectShow for it using  the follow schema:  create a grabber, add it to DS graph,  capture by it the audio/video streams and pass them to my AVstream drivers  for splitting.  But in new program I want to use  Media Foundation and  insert it into UWP.

How  I see my new app.  It must have Metro interface for common control:  choice of sources, adding parameters, changing modes and etc.  I'd like to use MediaCapture  class for  capture of streams  and rendering them  too.   Here I don't see any problems, MSDN has many samples for it.  But I have no ideas how to insert a grabber between source and render.

Which operations a grabber will do:

1. Receive input stream from MediaCapture.
2. Stream converting : YUV -> RGB, adding effects and etc.
3. Send output stream for rendering (MediaCapture) and to my AVstream driver for splitting with any apps (Skype, Adobe Flash Player, Edge, ....).

How to make a grabber. In MSDN I found three ways:

1. Sample Grabber Sink (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh184779(v=vs.85).aspx). No problem to receive/control/send stream in MF dll. But I don't know how to link that dll with  MediaCapture?
2. Source Reader (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940436(v=vs.85).aspx). The same problems, plus the Source Reader doesn't work for playback.
3. Custom MFT?  Any case MediaCapture allows to connect to MFT by AddEffectAsync().

My environment: MS Windows 10, MS Visual Studio Community 2015.

Thank you for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This question and UWP are not actual for me at all.  I found the following:

*"Some apps can work intensively in background, for example it maybe video converting, online financial data processing and more. 
Now UWP application will suspended when it go offscreen."*

https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/9950598-exclude-suspending-in-desktop

So if the user minimizes the program window, then the program stops  a video stream.